# enabled Textboxs not responding in change or ddbclick events

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Sub LMtgAmt_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim ProgError
    Dim TxtBox As MSForms.TextBox
    Set TxtBox = LMtgAmt
    MsgBox "in click"
    ' first variable is the control - textbox
    'the second variable is the topic:Mortgage =1, PSE = 2, Tacom Ut = 3...
    'The third variable is 1 for Todd and 2 for Linell
    ProgError = Processpayment(TxtBox, "1", "2")
    Exit Sub
End Sub
Sub LMtgAmt_Change()
    Dim ProgError
    Dim TxtBox As MSForms.TextBox
    Set TxtBox = LMtgAmt
    MsgBox "in Change"
    ' first variable is the control - textbox
    'the second variable is the topic:Mortgage =1, PSE = 2, Tacom Ut = 3...
    'The third variable is 1 for Todd and 2 for Linell
    ProgError = Processpayment(TxtBox, "1", "2")
End Sub
```

Comment: add 4 `blank` in front of each line of your code

Comment: Thank you. I tried the edit which suggested 2 blanks and that did nothing

Comment: Is this an activeX control or a forms control?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to find a cure other than cutting and replacing all 16 textboxes. That solved the problem but did not find a reason for then to have quit working.